# how to step through xml elements with the same name

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, foreach, element

Ok, so this is my second post on here and I am getting hung up with working with XML within vb.net, still.

I know how to grab the data I need for single elements with unique names, but what about if that process repeats?

My example, I am using an API to interact with a program at work. When I use the API to run a search for tickets related to a store # it returns multiple values like this:

```
<requests>
 <request>
 <form name="requestID">999999</form>
 <form name="userTimeFormat">EEE, MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy</form>
 <form name="contact">Contact Name</form>
 <form name="status">Status</form>
 <form name="statusID"></form>
 <form name="priority"></form>
 <form name="supportRep">Tom Smith</form>
 <form name="supportRepCostPerHour">0.00</form>
 <form name="createdTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="updatedTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="dueByTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="isOverDue">T/F</form>
 <form name="accountID"/>
 <form name="account"/>
 <form name="subject">Subject Goes Here</form>
 </request>

 <request>
 <form name="requestID">999998</form>
 <form name="userTimeFormat">EEE, MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy</form>
 <form name="contact">Contact Name</form>
 <form name="status">Status</form>
 <form name="statusID"></form>
 <form name="priority"></form>
 <form name="supportRep">Tom Smith</form>
 <form name="supportRepCostPerHour">0.00</form>
 <form name="createdTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="updatedTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="dueByTime">Time/Date</form>
 <form name="isOverDue">T/F</form>
 <form name="accountID"/>
 <form name="account"/>
 <form name="subject"> Subject Goes Here </form>
 </request>
```

So when I use XPath to grab information it works perfectly for the first < request > but my question is how do I move to the next < request > to get the next set of data?

here is my code that grabs it:

```
For Each requests As XElement In reader...<request>
            Dim ReqID As String = reader.XPathSelectElement("//form[@name='requestID']")
            Dim contact As String = reader.XPathSelectElement("//form[@name='contact']")
```

I know I need some sort of loop to to repeat the process but right now I'm at a loss. Any and all help/comments are appreciated. I am new to coding and vb, but I am a quick and eager learner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already select the `<request>` elements; but you have to use the XPath expression on each of those elements, not the root element:

```
For Each r in xml.XPathSelectElements("//request")
    Dim ReqID As String = r.XPathSelectElement(".//form[@name='requestID']")
    Dim contact As String = r.XPathSelectElement(".//form[@name='contact']")
    ' ...do something... '
Next
```

or, without XPath:

```
For Each request in xml...<request>
    Dim ReqID = request.<form>.Single(Function(f) f.@name = "requestID").Value
    Dim contact = request.<form>.Single(Function(f) f.@name = "contact").Value
    ' ...do something... '
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried both methods and they are still only getting the results from the first <request> and posting it for as many times as there are request.  My question would be, how to move down to the next request and get the next set of data? What its  out putting is this: 
999999
Contact ID
999999
Contact ID
999999
Contact ID etc...
What I'm trying to get is:
999999
Contact ID
999998
Contact ID etc... 

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Update: i realized I made a mistake elsewhere, all is working now! Thank you SO MUCH!